During phonepe integration using Reactjs and node I get 429 error
During phonepe integration using Reactjs and node I get 429 error.. What is the reason behind this
I tried using the keys provided by them in their testing environment itself but it is also giving the same error loke too many requests

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you found the resolution? Looks like this Phonepe UAT issue, may not occur in production environment. But, I am not sure how to do performance testing using UAT checkout. Also I think they have distributed the same MID and salt to many customer for testing and all of them making request at the same time. Midnight should be good for testing I guess, although I have not tested.

They must use property server.tomcat.threads.max=99999 in there UAT application, off course not in their prod.

Phonepe server UAT issue. You can find solution here

This is not any issue only you have to change the key. If you are using test key use this merchnat key : PGTESTPAYUAT86  and salt key : 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076
Merchant key : PGTESTPAYUAT86 
Salt Key : 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076

After 1 payment you have to may wait for some time to pay again.
This should taken care by Phonepe team but no idea why they are not looking on it.
You can also check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3j0DOmHcFA&pp=ygUgZmx1dHRlciBwaG9uZXBlIHBheW1lbnQgZ2F0ZXdheSA%3D

Why do we need to use this one itself?

This is test key and error is due to too many request on the same key. That is not ahndled by phonepe team.

I contacted phonepe support and they provided me with a UAT key and salt for that.

Yes they wil provide but if they not provide these test key can be used
